# Ramda IfElse best way to pass another parameter

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, functional-programming, ramda.js

In my NodeJS project which uses express and mongoose I decided to use RamdaJS to get some experience in functional programming.

I have two pre save hooks like

```
UserSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    if (!this.isModified('username')) {
        return next();
    }

    const total = await this.constructor.countUsersWithUsername(this.username);
    if (total > 0) {
        return next(new Error(`Username ${this.username} is already taken`));
    }

    return next();
});

UserSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    if (!this.isModified('email')) {
        return next();
    }

    const total = await this.constructor.countDocuments({ email: this.email });
    if (total > 0) {
        return next(new Error(`Email ${this.email} is taken`));
    }

    return next();
});
```

The If condition seems like a good place to use Ramda and I changed my code like

```
const total = await this.constructor.countUsersWithUsername(this.username);
const isUsernameTaken = R.ifElse(
    R.gt(0),
    () => next(),
    () => next(new Error(`Username ${this.username} is already taken`))
);
return isUsernameTaken(total);
```

This works but I started thinking I could refactor the IfElse into a different module and then I  would need to pass in next and a label so I could say ${label} ${value} is already taken.

How would I go about in refactoring this?

Mongoose is also class based based is there a functional library to connect with MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't bother doing this with Ramda.  Ramda's `ifElse` is occasionally very useful, but most of the time it's not worth it.  A conditional expression (ternary) is usually all that's needed.  Note that I'm a founder of Ramda and a big fan; but I there are many times when modern JS is just as good, or here, even older JS.

This would be my approach, without trying to figure out exactly how you'd call it inside your hooks:

```js
const isTaken = (label) => (value, count, next) =>
  count > 0
    ? next (new Error (`${label} ${value} is already taken`))
    : next ()

const isUsernameTaken = isTaken('Username')
const isEmailTaken = isTaken('Email')

const next = (err) => {
  console.log(err ? `${err}` : `Success`)
}

isUsernameTaken('Fred', 2, next);
isUsernameTaken('Wilma', 0, next);
isEmailTaken('fred@bedrock.com', 0, next)
isEmailTaken('wilma@stoneage.com', 1, next)
```

Whether you want the specific helpers `isUsernameTaken` and `isEmailTaken` or just want to call the generic `isTaken` would dictate whether you should curry the first parameter or not.  It should be quite easy to change.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful and nice reply Scott! I appreciate it!